# Death of Meta Tags revoked? Or why is there a beginner-guide tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Saw someone wanted to edit the wiki for the [beginner-guide](/questions/tagged/beginner-guide) tag.  [Has policy reversed so meta tags are in vogue... again](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) :/

If not, please remove the following tags:

- [beginners-guide](/questions/tagged/beginners-guide)
- [howto](/questions/tagged/howto)

Comment: No, I don't think it's been revoked. But it's [not entirely unheard of for these detestable tags to come back from the dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78963/destroy-the-weird-behavior-tag).

Comment: There's also 305 marked 'howto', which I found while looking at this

Comment: @ OMG po-diddy. if there are so many tags created by so many people - there is obviously a need. it does not come from no where. why not consolidate or address the issue. perhaps a SO - school version. or... i dunno. how about people that are studying and cannot afford a tutor and the fine minds on SO can help build the next moderator- you know what i mean? i think this line of thought is quite elitest

Comment: @noawithouth: No, creation/existence does not denote need.  SO is for crowd-sourcing help, not school.  The idea of doing someone's homeworks is still thoroughly loathed on SO.  "This line of thought" isn't elitist, it's about being concise with the five tags that are available for categorization so others can help and/or find the question/answer in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've eradicated the tag. No, there has not been a reversal on the meta tag policy. We spent a *considerable* amount of time and effort purging the others.

Unfortunately, it only takes one, then they multiply like crazy. The first one appeared to be a question saying "I don't know where to start in programming", where beginners-guide was the only tag. I just re-tagged it with several popular language tags since it's been closed for a while and the original author no longer has an account.

Anyway, I think that's how it ended up not getting swatted on sight. At least it didn't have a wiki or info page. :)

Comment: Thx Tim.  I rarely read meta, so I figured I'd ask if things have changed.