# Redirect tag "homework" traffic to a new "apprentice" tag?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

The [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) helps "clean the other tags" from more basic question traffic as well as creating a safe hub for new people and allows them an easier integration into the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: I wish you did state the obvious, because I have no idea what you're suggesting. Could you perhaps give an example?

Comment: will edit ... one sec.

Comment: You do realize that the homework tag is being removed, right?

Comment: @ bart:  that is funny you say so: since i was going to change the question to - protect the homework tag

Comment: And what do you mean by being more lenient when it comes to downvoting homework questions? More lenient how? We just look at question quality. If it's a good question, it's unlikely to get downvotes. The whole "imbalance" and goal of your question kind of escape me. You might want to clarify.

Comment: @ Bart- I edited the Questions...please see above.

Comment: Wow, that is quite the edit. And just saying it's a shame to remove it is not enough. You will have to tie it in with any of the previous discussions we've had on the issue on Meta. In this form it doesn't contribute a whole lot (if anything).

Comment: @ Could you direct me to a vivid one? (conversation)

Comment: Previous discussions are: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), [Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag), [The effects of removing the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148889/the-effects-of-removing-the-homework-tag)

Comment: @noawithouth Please read the FAQ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: possible duplicate of [Death of Meta Tags revoked? Or why is there a beginner-guide tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80382/death-of-meta-tags-revoked-or-why-is-there-a-beginner-guide-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for this, as discussed in the many previous discussions on the homework tag and its removal.

- [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)
- [Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag)
- [The Effects of Removing the Homework Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148889/the-effects-of-removing-the-homework-tag)

The principle is simple: Ask a good question. And a "good question" does not mean a "difficult question". Or "not a beginner question". It simply means that all we ask from a user is to do their own research first (including a good search of the site), formulate their question clearly, show us what they have tried so far and where they are stuck. You can meet those requirements at any level.

As such, there is no need for a tag to indicate any level of experience or the special circumstances under which the work is being performed. (As a part of their homework for example).

Yes, asking a good question is hard. And maybe there is a correlation between poor question asking ability and those working on homework. But I see no unfair handling of beginner questions by the community if the user demonstrates a reasonable amount of effort.

So in summary I see no reason to keep a homework tag or replace it by something else.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the acceptance of an answer, are you accepting it because this totally answers your question or because you want to stop the discussion and downvotes? If it's the latter, stop worrying about downvotes. Meta rep doesn't mean a thing. You are free to accept (or not) whenever you want and can safely leave this open for a while should you wish to do so. My answer is just one view. Perhaps other users have a different view.